# ASP.NET Web API 2 - How to implement OAuth2.0 for SPA applications

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application

I am trying to implement WEB API 2 (for Single Page App, not as part of Visual Studio project) OAuth2.0 protocol. As per [Which OAuth 2.0 flow should I use](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use), using refresh tokens is not an option. However, I am not sure I understand Implicit Grant flow with eventual Silent Authentication.

Does Implicit Flow mean only issuing normal access tokens? In that case, how do we allow user to stay logged in for long time? How should Silent Authentication endpoint look like, what should it receive and return to client? Is using refresh token really an issue - most of people have their usernames / passwords saved in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does Implicit Flow mean only issuing normal access tokens? Yes.

In that case, how do we allow user to stay logged in for long time? You can set timeout using "expires_in" parameter.

Refer for Complete Detail here: https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/implicit-grant/

How should Silent Authentication endpoint look like, what should it receive and return to client? Upon authentication of the user during login, the server sends & set the authentication key in the session/browser. So, during every page call, only authentication key is send to server. You shall find many examples of implementation online.

Is using refresh token really an issue - most of people have their usernames / passwords saved in browser? No, it's not an issue. If token expires, you can easily reissue token after authentication. Password & username is not saved in the browser. Only authentication key is stored.