# Authentication in javascript frontent, or in MVC backend?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, single-page-application, identityserver4

I'm trying to configure authentication in the following architecture:

1. A REST web api, done in asp.net core
2. An MVC client, where the 'view' is really a single page application (vue.js). For reference, I'm using this template: [TrilonIO](https://github.com/TrilonIO/aspnetcore-Vue-starter)

I want to use identity+identity server.

The way I understand it, my api is a secured resource: in order to access it, a user must sign in on identity server, and get a token.

My MVC app is one of the 'clients' of the identity server. Now, here is where I get confused:

Do I implement authentication on the mvc app, so that the main Index controller is protected? Then, in order to 'load' the spa, the user would have to authenticate on identity server, get a token, and then can load?

Or do I disregard implementing any authentication from the mvc side of things, and just use an oidc client to implement authentication from the browser side?

If I implement authentication on the mvc route, then essentially the user is authenticating twice: first, you are authenticating in order to access the view in the app. Once you're accessing the spa, you need to authenticate to access the web api. Will one 'login' suffice for both? How? Won't the tokens be configured differently?

If I only do authentication in the browser to access resources, then is my application "insecure"?

Any insight would be appreciated; I'm definitely new to this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your application would need to be secured.

If your front-end (browser, for instance) performs the authentication via some third-party then the web-api, or server-side application (if you are using something like asp.net mvc), would need to be notified from the front-end.  The web-api would then confirm with the third-party using the token, with possibly some extra data, to verify the authentication.  You could even perform this step with custom authentication on your server through the web-api.

That would take case of the authentication and we now have a token on the server that represents the authenticated user.

Each call back to the web-api / application would include some token that the web-api / application uses to see whether you are *authorised* to access the particular functionality.

This means that the bit that checks / registers the authentication along with the token would then use another mechanism, or even the same third-party if it supports authorisation, to obtain the authorisation.  I like to use a `uri` that represents a *permission* and then apply a filter to each web-api method that checks whether the received token has authorised access.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your response. The bit that I'm still confused about is this: do I authenticate the app as an mvc application, with the authentication configured in the startup.cs? In this case, in order to access the single view that the whole spa is built on, you'd need to authenticate, and get a token that allows you to access the rest api. This token could be passed back to the front end and then appended to all api calls. Alternatively, do I need to use an oidc-client to authenticate at the front-end?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to authenticate before serving the SPA code.  However, that isn't really necessary since your SPA would perform the authentication.  Your web-api is open anyway which is why you need the token to interact with it.  The SPA would also perform authorisation, probably using the same permissions from the initial credentials check, to prevent moving around the SPA although that is just a precaution since the user would not be able to interact with the web-api without a valid token.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So in that case, my authentication is done purely via the oidc-client? No need to implement it in the startup class of my mvc app? Thanks.

Comment: Here is a SO question that seems to be along the same lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646561/asp-net-web-api-2-how-to-implement-oauth2-0-for-spa-applications